# How to remove ONLY files without directories via terminal (macOS)

Tags: macos, terminal, rm

Can you help me with deleting files on mac? I want to delete only files from the directory and save other folders there.

`rm` and `find -delete`, but this is also deleting folders. Oh yes, folders in the name may contain dots. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find PATH -type f -delete
```

its work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).